# Bash - getting strange arguments when using $*

Tags: bash

When i define alias like:

```
alias strange="echo $*"
```

then

```
strange one two three
```

outputs:

```
completion-ignore-case on one two three
```

similary, for this alias:

```
alias strange2="echo $1 $2 $3 $4"
strange2 one two three four
completion-ignore-case on one two three four
```

I am on Windows, using git-bash...
Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Before assigning to the alias, `$*` gets expanded to current positional parameters and you actually have this in your alias: `echo completion-ignore-case on`. You can't use parameters with `alias`, use a function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases are intended for pure text expansion; they are not parameterized. However, you can simulate a limited form of parameter passing by using single quotes; this defers the expansion of `$*` until the alias is expanded, although it requires you to set the positional parameters manually before using the alias.

```
$ alias strange='echo $*'
$ set a b c
$ strange
a b c
$ set d e
$ strange
d e
```

Any "arguments" passed to the use are simply appended to the end of the alias expansion; that is, `strange 1 2 3` is first expanded to `echo $* 1 2 3`, which then undergoes the normal shell processing; the expansion of `$*` is unrelated to the following words.

For true parameterization, use a shell function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using double quotes doesn't prevent expansion to take place when setting the alias indeed `strange` will be aliased to `echo $*` where $* is replaced with current shell arguments. Use single quotes to prevent expansion, and use `alias strange` to see current alias definition.